# Can't understand class method & initializing

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I'm very new to programming and need some help understanding a few concepts.  I'm trying to create a method for class Book but keep getting a "no title= method" error.  How or what do I initialize to fix this error?

**Rspec Code**

```
before do
@book = Book.new
end

describe 'title' do
  it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
  @book.title = "inferno"
  @book.title.should == "Inferno"
end
```

**Here's my code**

```
class Book
  def title(string)
    string.downcase!
    string_temp = string.split

    small_words = ["a", "an", "the", "at", "by", "for", "in", "of", "over",
                 "on", "to", "up", "and", "as", "but", "it", "or", "nor"]  

    string_temp.map{|word| word.capitalize! unless small_words.include?(word)}

    string_temp[0].capitalize!
    string_temp.join(" ").strip        
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the `title=` and `title` methods:

```
class Book
  def title=(string)
    @title = string
  end

  def title
    @title
  end
end
```

This is the same as

```
class Book
  attr_writer :title
  attr_reader :title
end
```

And this can even be reduced to

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
end
```

But you will probably have a custom implementation for the writer:

```
class Book
  def title=(string)
    @title = titleize(string)
  end

  attr_reader :title

  private

  def titleize(string)
    #...
  end
end
```